# double precision error when converting to scientific notation

Tags: c++, unix, precision, double-precision, scientific-notation

I'm building a program to to convert double values in to scientific value format(mantissa, exponent). Then I noticed the below

```
369.7900000000000 -> 3.6978999999999997428

68600000 -> 6.8599999999999994316
```

I noticed the same pattern for several other values also. The maximum fractional error is

`0.000 000 000 000 001 = 1*e-15`

I know the inaccuracy in representing double values in a computer. Can this be concluded that the maximum fractional error we would get is `1*e-15`? What is significant about this?

I went through most of the questions on floating point precision problem in stack overflow, but I didnt see any about the maximum fractional error in 64 bits.

To be clear on the computation I do, I have mentioned my code snippet as well

```
double norm = 68600000;
if (norm)
{
    while (norm >= 10.0)
    {
      norm /= 10.0;
      exp++;
    }
    while (norm < 1.0)
    {
      norm *= 10.0;
      exp--;
    }
}
```

Now I get

```
norm = 6.8599999999999994316;
exp = 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you are getting is related to the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for the `double` data type.

A `double` is 64 bits long, with 1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52 bits for the mantissa fraction. A `double`'s value is given by

```
1.mmmmm... * (2^exp)
```

With only 52 bits for the mantissa, any `double` value below `2^-52` will be completely lost when added to `1.0` due to its small significance. In binary, `1.0 + 2^-52` would be

```
1.000...00  + 0.000...01  = 1.000.....01
```

Obviously anything lower would not change the value of `1.0`. You can verify for yourself that `1.0 + 2^-53 == 1.0` in a program.

This number `2^-52 = 2.22e-16` is called the **machine epsilon** and is an upper bound on the relative error that occurs during one floating point arithmetic due to round-off error with `double` values.

Similarly, `float` has 23 bits in its mantissa and so its machine epsilon is `2^-23 = 1.19e-7`.

The reason you are getting `1e-15` may be because errors accumulate as you perform many arithmetic operations, but I can't say because I don't know the exact calculations you are doing.

---

**EDIT**: I've looked into the relative error for your problem with 68600000.

First off, you may be interested to know that [round-off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) error can change the result of your computation if you break it into steps:

```
686.0/10.0      = 68.59999999999999431566
686.0/10.0/10.0 = 6.85999999999999943157
686.0/100.0     = 6.86000000000000031974
```

In the first line, the closest `double` to 68.6 is lower than the actual value, but in the third line we see the closest `double` to 6.86 is greater.

If we look at the **abosolute error** `e_abs = abs(v-v_approx)` of your program, we see that it is

```
6.8600000 - 6.85999999999999943156581139192 ~= 5.684e-16
```

However, the **relative error** `e_abs = abs( (v-v_approx)/ v) = abs(e_abs/v)` would be

```
5.684e-16 / 6.86  ~=  8.286e-17
```

Which is indeed below our machine epsilon of `2.22e-16`.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a famous paper you can read if you want to know all the details about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: thanks @eigenchris for that explanation. Now I slightly get the idea. But still I do not understand how my fractional error is more than  2.22e-16. As per the machine epsilon definition my fractional error should be less than 2.22e-16 isnt it?
btw I have added my code in the question

Comment: @vibz I updated my answer. The fractional error I got was different from yours and is below the machine epsilon. How did you calculate yours?

Comment: that explains it all @eigenchris.My calculation of fractural error was incorrect. Thank you :)